# Add transaction to sequelize

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

I'm starting with sequelize to create an API and I'm facing an issue with transactions.

My sequelize database configuration looks like this:

```
import databaseConfig from '../config/database';

import User from '../app/models/User';
import File from '../app/models/File';
import Address from '../app/models/Address';
import Customer from '../app/models/Customer';
import Product from '../app/models/Product';
import ServiceOrder from '../app/models/ServiceOrder';
import OrderStatus from '../app/models/OrderStatus';

const models = [
  User,
  File,
  Address,
  Customer,
  Product,
  ServiceOrder,
  OrderStatus,
];

class Database {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  async init() {
    this.connection = new Sequelize(databaseConfig);

    models
      .map(model => model.init(this.connection))
      .map(model => model.associate && model.associate(this.connection.models));
  }
}

export default new Database();
```

Then I have a orderStatusController with functions to save in database like this:

```
import sequelize from 'sequelize';
import OrderStatus from '../models/OrderStatus';

class OrderStatusController {
  async store(req, res) {
    sequelize
      .transaction(t => {
        return OrderStatus.create(
          {
            description: 'Aguardando Orçamento',
          },
          { transaction: t }
        );
      })
      .then(result => res.json(result))
      .catch(err => res.json({ error: err }));
  }
}

export default new OrderStatusController();
```

I got transaction is not a function error.

What is the best way to resolve this? 
I read that I need to instantiate the sequelize, but I already have a database configuration.

Is there any way to use my database configuration? 
I don't want to create another "new Sequelize()" within the controller.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way.  The my_db_app server code:

```
const sequelizeDB  = new Sequelize( myConfigOptions ); 

// other code...

server.listen(myPort, () => {

  sequelizeDB.Promise = global.Promise;
  sequelizeDB
      .authenticate()
      .then(() =>   { console.log('connected!');})
      .catch(err => { console.error(err);});

  // for controllers or models ...
  module.exports = {sequelizeDB : sequelizeDB}
```

Then a controller that needs a transaction can import the DB object:

```
   const db_app = require("../my_db_app");
   const sequelizeDB = db_app.sequelizeDB;

   // other code...

    sequelizeDB.transaction(function (myTransaction) {                    

        User.create({name: 'Joe', { transaction: myTransaction })
        .catch(function(error) {
           console.log("Error in User Create");
           throw error;
        });

        // other code on same transaction here...

    }).then(function () {
        console.log("SUCCESS!");
        next();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("FAILURE !");
    });
```

HTH